# How to force str(f) to yield the same output as f.__str__()?

Tags: python, oop

In the following code, I do not understand why `x.__str__()` and `str(x)` yield different results:

```
import gc

def mystr(self): return "{:.8f}".format(self)

underlying_dict = gc.get_referents(float.__dict__)[0]
underlying_dict["__repr__"] = mystr
underlying_dict["__str__"] = mystr

# I want to see 0.12345679
x = 0.123456789

print 1, "{:.8f}".format(x) # works
print 2, mystr(x)           # works
print 3, x                  # fails
print 4, x.__str__()        # works
print 5, x.__repr__()       # works
print 6, str(x)             # fails
print 7, type(x)            # just checking the type
```

Answer (score 1):

I have restricted the question to comparing `str(x)` and `x.__str__()`.

In the REPL (Python 2 or Python 3):

```
>>> x = 0.123456789
>>> print(str(x))
0.123456789
>>> print(x.__str__())
0.123456789
```

With IPython3:

```
In [2]: x = 0.123456789
   ...:    ...: print(str(x))
   ...:    ...: print(x.__str__())
   ...: 
0.123456789
0.123456789
```

But I get the same problem as you when I execute it in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
x = 0.123456789
print(str(x))
print(x.__str__())

#0.123456789
#0.12345679
```

So, the problem seems to be related to Jupyter. But I haven't found more about it yet...